# Oracle SQL display distinct none "standard alphanumeric caracters

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I need to find the way to list all the characters used in the column in order to narrow down the "Approved" values within the insert template we are creating...
the idea is to allow all letters (only standard) without any dialect / country specific ones.

trying something like this... but need to have a list of the characters left over... like "$%()* etc.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(column_1,^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$)
```

Comment: I googled "oracle find special characters in string" and I really got a lot of hits. Did you go through those ? What didn't work ? Can you provided a bit of sample data with the expected behaviour ?

Answer (score 1):

To find the other characters, you could remove the ones you do expect and then see what is left:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( column1, '[a-zA-Z0-9-]' ) AS other_characters
FROM   mytable
WHERE  REGEXP_REPLACE( column1, '[a-zA-Z0-9-]' ) IS NOT NULL
```

If you want to concatenate and remove duplicate characters:

```sql
WITH replace_expected ( str ) AS (
  SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( column1, '[a-zA-Z0-9-]' )
  FROM   mytable
  WHERE  REGEXP_REPLACE( column1, '[a-zA-Z0-9-]' ) IS NOT NULL
),
split_strings ( str, pos, ch ) AS (
  SELECT str, 1, SUBSTR(str, 1, 1)
  FROM   replace_expected
UNION ALL
  SELECT str, pos + 1, SUBSTR(str, pos + 1, 1)
  FROM   split_strings
  WHERE  pos < LENGTH(str)
)
SELECT LISTAGG(DISTINCT ch) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ch) AS other_characters
FROM   split_strings;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nrSW2sc1)

Answer (score 0):

Two steps:

1. Extract the special characters from all strings in the column and concatenate them into one long string (with possibly many characters appearing multifold in the string).
2. Use a recursive query to loop through the characters and return a string with distinct characters.

The query:

```
with one_row (str) as
(
  select listagg(regexp_replace(column_1, '[a-zA-Z0-9\-]'))
  from mytable
  where regexp_like(column_1, '[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]')
)
select listagg(distinct substr(str, level, 1)) as c
from one_row
connect by level <= length(str);
```

Comment: This works if you can guarantee that the first part will be 4000 or less characters. However, if you have more than 4000 non-distinct characters aggregated in the sub-query factoring clause then that will fail with `ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long`. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/X_kJfsrf)

Comment: @MT0: Yes, this is correct. I should have mentioned this. The query is fast and slender, but has this drawback.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table dummy_data as 
    select rownum as id, dbms_random.string(opt, len) str
     from (
       select case round(dbms_random.value(0, 3))
                when 0 then 'a' 
                 when 1 then 'x' 
                else 'p'  
             end opt,
             round(dbms_random.value(5, 60)) len
    from dual connect by level <= 30 );

SELECT * FROM DUMMY_DATA;


ID  STR
1   UMUUJ0R5VM1T3X10TDCNIWC3MQ5ELOB041YMNEJSLT
2   _t8 }LeZhjiMB"8/a'/~a 
3   BLSE6XX6SL3M7W0DG3HH28SCHPSAT11ZH2E5DOSKEV3KW9
4   1]Mh58(l<Wa}{
5   :_QiWUkwp}V$}O
6   NC911A4SRN35CNXT2EU5H2GZ67IQQLKH
7   e"8,z$=Yvy5egvEH2KUkNoVjkitd9IMm0ZktsB i(bk4uU]c3;E
8   MgbpIsLZpWEcAghOUKOISA
9   7H02ASKO3CZRN4D5FUNPEU6YUZD
10  KbJ+QrI\l.th%>^f!Io%wshsVA%
11  PO9A47VU7AXI17XYD5VMSWW8E
12  1ILWL4V
13  FgubwibYBytNvmJHxUfG
14  ?[ngH?0!k.onN>mF(nrkO
15  86G0HP3
16  WXDBV3OBMVSDKQ59YT73G0II3U94
17  GP375CFIQPPN6216I5A7L54O
18  i\L<K,"d'ye 6s~_MB0O1 aC$q;T"EaqpZ^s\gIiYu&:%OnhVj]<a]CmOgqM
19  WxUEtr\II(97i7PQ-Z]yqd#&`@CQB0M"c0;{.by9qo#HT
20  IF5OP7KS9AXW91
21  HNcKwxXozXjTVwKeFZDLdmNOzFKKKq
22  4D8CINXIVT244RDDRZ5TSDQ4CRF4
23  3)oxevW-(~=+@cP[^g)@#|1.TL-_N9O-Zdgj"cwJC'*NR; FtK)K
24  AndzeLIEPklDuTWWEBrKrdNKdXwMGeLauJkRzKpKHEGAsxlEXliwBTHdK
25  dlEX1tGFuU5\5+{5`R
26   /W0.{B&)ax&lWEE#OSw
27  CBKOVLKDFKC3EVR
28  :V@Lc.Z"8[O-)cAWUpMjc?j\Kj?xV@%`Yp [VkEV1
29  P9P047
30  W)S<fB`F;N_brMP

with
  h (ok_chars) as (
    select '0123456789' ||          'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' ||
           'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    from   dual
  )
select c, count(*) as cnt
from   dummy_data cross join lateral (
         select  substr(str, level, 1) as c
         from    h
         where   instr(ok_chars, substr(str, level, 1)) = 0
         connect by level <= length(str)
       )
group  by c;

C CNT
}   4
-   5
'   3
<   4
,   2
=   2
_   5
(   5
^   3
[   4
"   7
/   3
:   3
.   6
%   5
!   2
?   4
`   4
    8
;   5
+   3
>   2
)   6
|   1
*   1
~   3
\   6
&   4
@   5
]   5
{   4
#   4
$   3
```